# How to get all elements that have "click" event attached with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, event-handling, click

There is well known problem with IOS that it does not recognize `click` event unless the element has css `cursor: pointer;`

However I do not want all clickable elements to have this behavior on desktop so I am looking for a way to add this css only if IOS is detected.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)){
    var elements = /* here I need help to get all elements that have click event
    attached, taking into account that some of them could be added dynamically */
    elements.css('cursor', 'pointer');
}
```

Do not know If that is even possible  but I really want to find a good way to not worry about IOS clicks.

UPDATE:
The idea would be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').on('click', 'div.hasClick', function(){
      // do something
   });
   /* much more similar click event attached to many elements*/
   if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)){
        var elements = /* here I need help to get all elements that have click event
        attached, taking into account that some of them could be added dynamically 
*/
        elements.css('cursor', 'pointer');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not just add a class with jquery and use css using media query?

Answer (score 1):

Do you meant this?

```js
$('*[onclick]').css("cursor","pointer");
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  background: blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="javascript:void(0)"></div>
<div onclick="javascript:void(0)"></div>
<div id="onclk"></div>
```

Comment: No. I added some edits to question. Click events are added with jquery not as attribute

Answer (score 1):

Searching entire DOM for things which has click event is going to be costly. Assuming you know the subset you want to check for existence of a click event, you could do something like this...

```
let elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("button"));
let elementsWithEvent = [];

elementsWithEvent = elements.filter((element)=>{
    return $(element).data('events').click ? true : false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Praveen.  i was wondering if you can please provide this piece of code in plain Javascript (not JQuery). I'd really really appreciate it!!!! :)